# how to show dropdown (already apply select it not display)in angular .js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make select option using json .I don't know why it is not display .I used select then inside that I used option tag ..

```
 <div ng-switch-when="SWITCH">
           <select name="selectedFacilityId" ng-model="outputs[input.name]">
     <option ng:repeat="v in inputValues" value="{{v}}">{{v}}</option>
 </select>
            </div>
```

Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/EM3tqekUxaiUZA1b7Fk4?p=preview

```
  angular.forEach($scope.formInputs, function(value, key) {
    /* do something for all key: value pairs */


    $scope.inputs.push({"inputValues":value.inputValues,"type":value.inputType.toLowerCase(),"name":value.name,"required": value.required})
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to working plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/ynrulC71EK1qn3p2qo8R?p=preview

1) You used 'SWITCH' instead of 'switch' inside 'ng-switch-when' directive. In your $scope this value is lower-case.

```
<div ng-switch-when="switch"> .. </div>
```

2) Ng-repeat directive now uses key-value form:

```
<option ng-repeat="(k,v) in input.inputValues" value="{{k}}">{{v}}</option>
```

Comment: how to apply css in give dropdow